# How to sort nested JSON in the markup

Tags: jquery, html, json, sorting, toggle

I am building a huge nested json file. On the page I want to be able to sort based on some of the nested elements. Certain pages will only show certain nests but I want to also be able to sort between categories.

For example, I need to know how to write: display all, display wire only, display GDes new only, display GDes old only etc. Any idea on how to create a simple toggle in the markup

[
        {"wire":[
            {"new":[
                {
                "url": "http://galnova.com/",
                "folder": "pro_images"
                },
                {
                "url": "http://galnova.com/",
                "folder": "pro_images"
                }
            ]}
        ]},

```
    {"GDes":[
        {"new":[
            {
            "url": "http://galnova.com/",
            "folder": "nu_images"
            },
            {
            "url": "http://galnova.com/",
            "folder": "nu_images"
            }
        ]}
    ]},

    {"GDes":[
        {"old":[
            {
            "url": "http://galnova.com/",
            "folder": "nu_images"
            },
            {
            "url": "http://galnova.com/",
            "folder": "nu_images"
            }
        ]}
    ]},

    {"Web":[
        {"new":[
            {
            "url": "http://galnova.com/",
            "folder": "nu_images"
            }
        ]}
    ]}
]
```

Comment: You need a code for sort this json or a better model of json?

Comment: What have **you** tried?

Comment: Try `JSON.parse` and underscore.js or lodash.